# iOS: registerForRemoteNoficationTypes, what happens next?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Everytime my `applicationDidBecomeActive` event is fired, I call the method `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes`.

I understand there are 2 possible outcomes after this, either all went well and the event `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is fired and the `DeviceToken` is returned.

The second outcome is if something fails, then the `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` event gets fired and has an error message attached to it.

My question is, what happens if I call the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` method, but the user has disabled push notifications for my app? Why does this not count as a fail and fire `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`? What exactly is going on? There has to be some event that gets fired right?

Comment: there is also method in `UIApplication`  `(UIRemoteNotificationType)enabledRemoteNotificationTypes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` does not go to users' devices, it goes to APNS (Apple Push Notification Server) server and registers the app for push notifications. There only it generates the device token at Apple's server and gives it back to the app.

`didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` is called only if the app fails to register itself with APNS.

There is one way only to know if any user is actually having the push notification switched off (or having the phone shut down for that matter). When APNS tries and fails to send push notification to a particular device multiple times, it puts it into a pool which is provided back to the app in a feedback service, so that the application server (not APNS) can remove it from its database.

This link gives you more information about feedback service: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3

To check if the user has disabled any notification type for your app the following method can be used:

```
- (NSRemoteNotificationType)enabledRemoteNotificationTypes
```

Apple says: The values in the returned bit mask (NSRemoteNotificationType) indicate the types of notifications currently enabled for the app. These types are first set when the app calls the registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: method to register itself with Apple Push Notification Service. Thereafter, the user may modify these accepted notification types in the Notifications preference of the Settings app. This method returns those initial or modified values. iOS does not display or play notification types specified in the notification payload that are not one of the enabled types. For example, the app might accept icon-badging as a form of notification, but might reject sounds and alert messages, even if they are specified in the notification payload.

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) 
{
  //Do your stuff
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So if the user has push disabled for my app, calling `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` does nothing?

Comment: It still generates the device token if succeeds with registering to Apple push service. I think just in case you enable the notification after the app is launched - as it will not be able to register for Push notification unless it is relaunched.

Comment: So, basically if `(NSRemoteNotificationType)enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` returns nothing, then this means the user has push disabled?

Comment: Yes, the code will be as follows:

UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) 
{
  //do your stuff
}